# on click of each li get the ids of all li with same class

Tags: jquery

i have a DOM element like below

```
<ul id="names">
   <li id="aa" class="selected">aa</li>
   <li id="bb">bb</li>
   <li id="cc">cc</li>
   <li id="dd">dd</li>
</ul>
```

When i click on an li element a class "selected" is added to that element. and on click of a selected li the class is removed. 
Now every time i click on an li i need to create an array with all the li elements that are selected.

if aa and bb are selected then my array should look like this ["aa", "bb"]
and when i uselect bb and select cc it should become ['aa','cc']. The array should be created on click of the li and not on click of any button.

How can i do this with query? 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Try this using `.map()`

```
var selectedID = $('#names li.selected').map(function(){
  return this.id;
}).get();
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Alfie/eBhhX/)

To get all ids in an array do this

```
$('#All').on('click',function(){
    var selectedID = $('#names li').not(this).map(function(){
      return this.id;
    }).get();
});
```

or use siblings()

```
$('#All').on('click',function(){
    var selectedID = $(this).siblings('li').map(function(){
      return this.id;
    }).get();
    console.log(selectedID);
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Alfie/eBhhX/1/)

Comment: Thanks. Now if i have another li element <li id="All">All</li>. And when i click on all then the array formed should be ["aa","bb","cc","dd"] where these lis now dont have the class selected. how can i do that

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[map()](http://api.jquery.com/map/)**:

```
var selectedLis = $('#names li.selected').map(function() { 
  return this.id; 
}).get();

console.log(selectedLis);
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4LuAc/1/)**

---

Edit: Based on your comment, you can do:

```
$('#All').click(function () {
    var selectedLis = $('#names li').not(this).map(function () {
        return this.id;
    }).get();

    console.log(selectedLis);
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4LuAc/2/)**

Comment: Thanks. Now if i have another li element <li id="All">All</li>. And when i click on all then the array formed should be ["aa","bb","cc","dd"] where these lis now dont have the class selected. how can i do that.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want an array of `id`s where that element has a class of `selected`, just map the elements' `id`s to an array with jQuery's `map()`, anytime you need to get them:

```
var ids = $('#names .selected').map(function(){
    return this.id;
}).get();
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mpqL7/)

Comment: Thanks. Now if i have another li element <li id="All">All</li>. And when i click on all then the array formed should be ["aa","bb","cc","dd"] where these lis now dont have the class selected. how can i do that